# Avoid pgAdmin4 timeout that prevents disconnect

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, timeout

Connecting to PostgreSQL servers through pgAdmin4 will time out after some short period of time (2-5 min). When this happens I cannot reset the connection or disconnect from the server. The interface becomes unresponsive and I am unable to perform any further work without restarting the entire pgAdmin4 webserver.

How can I prevent this happening or otherwise configure pgAdmin4 to allow easier reset/disconnect from servers?

Quick addendum: the connections will eventually reset if I leave the server alone for a while but I do not know how to manually force this behaviour.

Comment: What versions?  Is it the connection attempts that time out, or already established connections?  If you get an error message, what is it?  Looking in the db log file, what does it say about the lost connections?